# .NET Code128 & PDF417 Barcode Library

Tags: .net, barcode

Can anyone *recommend* a barcode creation library for use in a .NET application library. I need one that supports:

- Code128
- PDF417
- Ideally optimised for .NET 4
- Ideally open source, but paid-for library also acceptable

NOTE: I have already seen the BarcodeRender project on codeplex - I'm after recommendations

Thanks,

Comment: There's a free one called [GenCode128](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/GenCode128.aspx), but it only supports code 128 and for .net 2

Comment: Thanks, but I already found loads of libraries that support Code128. PDF417 seems to be the unloved cousin...

Comment: GenCode 128 is the fastest one that i found! It can generate 1k barcodes in 800ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try [Aspose.BarCode for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.barcode-for-.net/default.aspx). This component allows you to create and read bar codes. It can [work with Code128, PDF417 and many other symbologies](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.barcode-for-.net/product-overview.html). You can even work with 2D bar codes. It works perfectly with .NET 4.0 on both 32/64-bit systems. It is not free but provide a lot of features along with quality support. You may [download a trial version](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.barcode-for-.net/default.aspx).

Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: I work for ByteScout currently

[ByteScout BarCode SDK](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/barcodesdk/bytescoutbarcodesdk.html) - paid library but generates both Code128 and PDF417 under the same license (some tools have separate licenses for Code128 and PDF417 generation)

Answer (score 1):

I've worked for several years on a commercial software product that uses [Neodynamic's Barcode Professional](http://www.neodynamic.com/DesktopDefault.aspx).

It's a set of commercial products and they annoyingly split it along technology lines (Barcode Professional "...for ASP.NET", "...for WinForms", etc., but it does work well and it supports the symbologies you listed.

I'm not sure what you are after with "optimized for .NET 4."  The API interaction for barcode generation should be pretty cut-and-dry.  Beyond support for use in applications that target .NET 4, what optimization where you hoping for?

Comment: Have you used the WPF version? I'm having trouble with PDF417 barcodes being drawn outside the bounds of the barcode element on my pages. I could set the `FitBarcodeToSize` property to constrain it, but that does seem a shame given auto flow/layout in WPF is normally so well done.

Comment: @NeilBarnwell I have not used the WPF version, so I'm afraid I can't address your question.